# Accessibility tabbing and enter through link on a span element

Tags: php, html, css, accessibility

so as the title says. Maybe this is just not possible the way I have it structured, but I want to make sure this works for accessibility. I have a grid of logo images that are positioned in a styled span. The logo has a link to that company's website. I can tab through the individual items by adding `tabindex="0"` but I cannot hit enter or space to trigger link to be visited. What am I missing here? If I change the `<span>` to a `<button>` it works but that seems sloppy to me?

Here is how my code is structured:

```
<span class="grid_item" role="link" tabindex="0">

    <a href="<?= $url ?>" aria-label="Go to <?= $logo_title ?> website" tabindex="0">
        <img alt="<?= $logo_title ?>" src="<?= $image['url'] ?>">
    </a>

</span>
```

I've tried changing the span to a `<div>` and a `<ul>` with line items but still all same issue with no click through. I would love any input on this, to not only solve this but also for me to have a better understanding of the way accessibility works.

Comment: Your code works, I have tested it just now. Check the URL you are getting inside the href of the a tag.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you can create an accessible solution using all native HTML and not need `tabindex` or any [ARIA attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#x6-6-definitions-of-states-and-properties-all-aria-attributes).  In fact, [the first rule of ARIA use](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#rule1) is to *not* use ARIA.

In your original code, having a `tabindex="0"` on the `<span>` **and** having a nested `<a>` will cause *two* <kbd>tab</kbd> stops.  And it will be even more confusing because both tab stops will announce the element as a "link" - the `<span>` has [`role="link"`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#link) and the `<a>` is natively a link.

Keep it simple.  You shouldn't need any accessibility related attributes on the `<span>`.  Just let the span be the container for the link and do whatever styling you want to do (remove `tabindex` and `role`).  Then let the `<a>` do its thing and be a native tab stop and natively allow the <kbd>enter</kbd> to trigger it.  (<kbd>space</kbd> is not natively supported on a `<a>`.)

Comment: Are you saying something like this?
```<span class="grid_item">

            <a href="<?= $url ?>" aria-label="Go to <?= $logo_title ?> website">
                <img alt="<?= $logo_title ?>" src="<?= $image['url'] ?>">
            </a>
        </span>```
I tried this and it doesn't seem to tab through anything at all and just skips the component completely

Comment: Yes.  Not sure why you can't tab to it.  I copied/pasted your code and it works.  If your `<a>` doesn't have an `href` attribute, then that would make it a placeholder link which does **not** receive keyboard focus by default.  But in your comment, you **do** have an `href` and I'm able to tab to it.

Comment: So I got this to work by removing the span entirely, and I threw the styling class on to the <a> tag itself and all works fine now. 

I’m really not sure why it didn’t work with the div or span there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think I resolved this. I am not sure if this is the correct way, but I wrapped the entire span in the `<a>` tag. Is this semantic?

Comment: Does that mean your new `<a>` element that wraps the `<span>`  will also have a nested `<a>` ?  That would not be valid HTML.  A link cannot have a nested link.

Comment: These kind of answers are better written as a comment

Comment: No I removed the <a> from inside the span so it looks like the following now 

```<a href="<?= $url ?>" aria-label="Go to <?= $logo_title ?> website" tabindex="0">
    <span class="grid_item" role="link" tabindex="0">
        <img alt="<?= $logo_title ?>" src="<?= $image['url'] ?>"></span>
</a>```